# Executing multiple commands using winexe

Tags: linux, windows, mount, samba

```
./bin/winexe -U <username>%<password> //<ip> "cmd.exe /c net use x: \\\\<ip>\\share    /user:<user> <password>"
```

This command works fine, but for me to run another command to use this mapped drive, another run of /bin/winexe gives me access denied.

I cannot run multiple commands like below using a semicolon

```
./bin/winexe -U <username>%<password> //<ip> "cmd.exe /c net use x: \\\\<ip>\\share    /user:<user> <password> ; cmd.exe /c copy X:\something c:"
```

But if i do this, it works. but i cannot automate this:

```
./bin/winexe -U <username>%<password> //<ip> "cmd.exe"
C:\Windows\system32> net use x: \\\\<ip>\\share    /user:<user> <password> 
C:\Windows\system32> copy x:\something c:
```

My requirement is to install a msi package which is on a network share using winexe. Using expect is my last option

Answer (score 0):

You can use "&" instead of semicolon.

The correct way to execute multiple commands via cmd:

dir & echo foo